# REST API response includes "This XML file does not appear..."

Tags: json, api, rest

I've created a REST API but when I call it with a GET, it returns this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<ArrayOfgetSiteList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Thor">
<getSiteList>
<responseCode>1</responseCode>
<responseMessage>No message</responseMessage>
<sites>
<Sites>
<siteAddress>11 Main Street054656</siteAddress>
<siteId>1</siteId>
<siteName>Sky Towers</siteName>
</Sites>
<Sites>
<siteAddress>1 Grande Street</siteAddress>
<siteId>2</siteId>
<siteName>Hotel Grande</siteName>
</Sites>
</sites>
</getSiteList>
</ArrayOfgetSiteList>
```

How do I get it to return just the JSON text within the square brackets, and not the "This XML file..." part? Are there some headers I am supposed to add to the response, and if so how/where do I add it?

Also, how do I get it to be formatted/indented nicely like http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/mykey/myvalue/anotherkey/anothervalue?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: that's not xml... that's JSON. Exactly how are you outputting this json? if it's something silly like `header('Content-type: text/xml'); echo json_encode($arr);`, then you're getting exactly what you told the system to do: output json and lie that it's xml.

Comment: That's because the XML is JSON...

Comment: I didn't deliberately add any headers. I followed http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms and output the JSON as a List. Where should I be adding the headers? When I run it on Postman, it gives me the JSON output I'm seeking. But when I run it on a web browser (Chrome), the above output appears.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `PartialView()` you should return `Json()` as your `ActionResult`.

```
return Json(someItem,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: This is an extremely framework-specific answer to a language-agnostic question.

Comment: Thanks. I am outputting the JSON using C#. And my API controller is returning a string. My question is: what should I put in the string besides what's inside the square brackets?